# Cant deploy site on either github pages or netlify. Nuxt2 and Tailwind project

Tags: github, deployment, nuxt.js, netlify

Hello i have build a project in Nuxt2 and Tailwind. But I cant deploy it on github pages or netflify..
Here is my project in guthub https://github.com/Astborg/cocktailappNuxt/

On github pages its just loading..

[image]

[image]

on netlify it failes;
[image]

Comment: Do you really need `router.base: '/Astborg/cocktailappNuxt/'`?

Comment: I dont know I if need it, I followed some debugging and it said I should add this :)

Comment: In your `nuxt.config.js` yes, check mine for comparison. That one is not really needed tbh.

Comment: I have made the changes you did :)) and deleted this in the config etc. I get this error and failed on Netlify; 1:16:38 PM: git ref refs/heads/main does not exist or you do not have permission

Comment: This is more of a git issue or accounts you're connected with. Be sure to connect on Netlify with your GitHub account. Maybe check a video on YouTube on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the URL of a hosted app: https://vocal-dusk-d7176e.netlify.app/

Here are my build settings

[image]

And here are some changes that I did to your project to have it properly hosted on Netlify: https://github.com/kissu/cocktailappNuxt/blob/main/nuxt.config.js#L3

Comment: Thank you for your update. I get unfortunately same error on Netlify :/  But I cant choose branch to deploy it says its none to choose from.

Comment: @tocajossan how are you trying to link it to Netlify? If you take my GitHub repo, you will get no errors deploying it.

Comment: true it works for you! Thats good, but weird it doesnt work for me..

Answer (score 0):

Simplest advice for you:

- Build from `main`
- Add an `index.html` and `.nojekyll` file in the root
- Make sure the builds restart and you're page will be up and running.

Comment: No need for `index.html` and I'm not sure what `.nojekyll` will be used for here.

Comment: Okey what do you suggest instead? thx